# Why gcc does not create a new variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, constants, compiler-optimization

I have such code:

```
static const char kFmt[] = "some string: - %s";
char buf[sizeof(kFmt) + 10];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), kFmt, "string");
```

It looks like arm gcc 6.3.0 does not create an additional char array `kFmt` in RAM, but instead just passes the pointer to string literal  (stored in flash memory in my case) to `snprintf`.

But if I remove `const` and have `static char kFmt[]` I can see that an **additional** array is created in RAM and then passed to `snprintf`.

It is not a problem but I wonder if this behavior is described somewhere in C++ standard or it is compiler optimization and it might differ in different compilers?

Comment: The compiler can perform any optimization that doesn't change the observable behavior of the program. The [As-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) in the standard is a blanket permission for all such optimizations.

Comment: Yes, the question is not about possibility of such optimization. It is perfectly well optimization. The question is there rule that dictates such behavior for any compiler. 
Any link to gcc docs where they describe such optimization is also very welcomed

Comment: @KonstantinT. What kind of rule do you expect to see? The observable behavior of your program isn't affected by whether or not the string literal is passed directly to `snprintf`, so it is up to the compiler whether or not it does so. The GCC docs will not list concrete rules for all individual optimizations performed by the compiler. Or do you just want to know which of the optimization passes/flags is responsible for this?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the standard that would require this optimization be performed.

Comment: Why should it? Why do think it would be correct way of doing it?

Comment: @user17732522 observable behavior does not but memory consumption might. I don't want to have two copy of the string one in RAM and another in flash, so I thinking  should I use const pointer and be sure that there is no additional buffer in RAM, or I can count on described behavior and  be sure that no matter what compiler version/flag/whatever I use there is no addition  memory consumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard does not deal with RAM or flash memory. It is the implementation that decides where and how data are stored.

However, the standard does say that a const object cannot be modified, so I'd expect a sensible implementation to store `static const` objects in read-only memory if that's most efficient. On the other hand, non-const objects generally have to live in writable memory.

[[dcl.type.cv]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4):

> Any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
Strictly ```static const char kFmt[] = ""``` mean that I create char array in static storage, and copy string literal into it. But I see that gcc doesn't do it, so be it, but  I would like to find the scope of such optimization. Not to find out one day, that in new compiler version this behavior is changed :)

Comment: Note:  constant objects and live in the executable as well.  The IAR compiler is placing a lot of data inside the executable section.

Comment: @KonstantinT.: No, that's not what `static const char kFmt[] = ...` means.  The `"string"` is an *initializer*, not a separate string literal that's being copied at any point during your program's lifetime.  The array is `const` with a constexpr initializer so it's truly read-only: it has an initial value and can never change. It's just syntactic sugar for `static const char kFmt[] = {'s', 't', ..., 0};`

Comment: @KonstantinT.: In your question, you said the compiler just passes "the string literal", implying that there's no `kFmt` label anywhere.  But that's not the case, `main::kFmt` should be the label (after demangling) on the read-only storage containing the ASCII bytes.  https://godbolt.org/z/3T6oWzWPx shows that's the case.

Comment: Thank you guys! This answer along with comments makes it clear for me.